# How do I create a TypeScript type with dynamic properties based on another property?

Tags: typescript, types

I'd like to create a TypeScript definition that uses the strings provided in `headers` to be the names of properties nested in that type, as below:

```
obj = {
  headers: ['first', 'second', 'third'],
  first: [{
    id: 'someStrA',
    second: [{
      id: 'someStrB',
      third: [{
        id: 'someStrC'
      }],
    }],
  }]
}
```

This object will be used in an *n*-dimensional view, where *n* is the length of `headers`, but *n* can vary based on what exactly is being presented.

Comment: Could you make that `..` something real and concrete so this is a [mre]?  The answer to this will be that there's no *specific* type corresponding to this, but you can make a *generic* type that acts as a constraint.

Comment: I edited for clarification. Each of the levels of nested objects will only have `id`; the only difference would be the order of the nesting.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mpgBgN) meet your needs?  If not please let me know what I'm missing; otherwise I can write up an answer.

Comment: @jcalz this fits the use case perfectly -- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific `Obj` type in TypeScript that corresponds to your set of desired values.  The constraint between the members of the `headers` property and the keys of the other properties cannot be expressed directly.  However, you can create a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `Obj<H>` type where the `H` type parameter corresponds to the [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) from the `headers` property.  If you know `H` is, for example, `["first", "second", "third"]`, then `Obj<["first", "second", "third"]>` would be a specific type that acts as you want.  Here's how `Obj<H>` might look:

```
type Obj<H extends string[]> = { headers: H } & ObjProps<H>

type ObjProps<H> = H extends [infer H0, ...infer HR] ? {
    [P in Extract<H0, string>]: ({ id: string } & ObjProps<HR>)[]
} : unknown
```

So an object of type `Obj<H>` has a `headers` property of type `H`, and it is also (via [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types)) a value of type `ObjProps<H>`, which takes care of the nesting.

The `ObjProps<H>` type uses [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to split the `H` type into its first element `H0` and the rest of the elements `HR`.  Then `ObjProps<H>` has a property whose key is `H0` (that's the [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) `{[P in Extract<H0, string>]: ...}`) and whose value is an array of object types with a `string`-valued `id` property which is also an `ObjProps<HR>` (meaning we recurse down).  If `H` is the empty tuple then `ObjProps<H>` is [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) which is our base case.

Let's just make sure this looks like what we want:

```
type ConcreteObj = Obj<["first", "second", "third"]>;
/* type ConcreteObj = {
    headers: ["first", "second", "third"];
} & {
    first: ({
        id: string;
    } & {
        second: ({
            id: string;
        } & {
            third: {
                id: string;
            }[];
        })[];
    })[];
} */
```

eh, that's a little ugly; let's collapse those intersections:

```
type Expand<T> = T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: Expand<T[K]> } : T;
type ExpandedConcrete = Expand<ConcreteObj>;
/* type ExpandedConcrete = {
    headers: ["first", "second", "third"];
    first: {
        id: string;
        second: {
            id: string;
            third: {
                id: string;
            }[];
        }[];
    }[];
} */
```

Looks good!

---

Of course you probably don't want to have to [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) `obj` with the `Obj<["first", "second", "third"]>` type.  You'd probably like the compiler to infer `["first", "second", "third"]` from `obj`.  You can get this to happen with the aid of a generic helper function:

```
const asObj = <H extends string[]>(obj: Obj<[...H]>) => obj;
```

And then instead of annotating `obj` you just infer its type from the result of `asObj()`:

```
const obj = asObj({
    headers: ['first', 'second', 'third'],
    first: [{
        id: 'someStrA',
        second: [{
            id: 'someStrB',
            third: [{
                id: 'someStrC'
            }],
        }],
    }]
});
// const obj: Obj<["first", "second", "third"]>
```

This helper function also catches mistakes, since it requires that the object passed in is a valid `Obj<H>` for the `H` inferred from the `headers` property:

```
const badObj = asObj({
    headers: ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'],
    first: [{
        id: 'someStrA',
        second: [{
            id: 'someStrB',
            third: [{
                id: 'someStrC' // error!  Property 'fourth' is missing 
            }],
        }],
    }]
});
```

Note that by making `Obj<H>` generic it might force you to add generic type parameters to other places in your code, or do other workarounds to prevent that.  But that's out of scope for the question as asked (and would take a long time to go over here) so I'll skip it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#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-Ki7J5uNblKr9f7-KbtKFzKkkvRRMnYunArnMhlg1JFDgAhIbzgmG1lj1vcYrFyBpQEiqCw8bgwrAaHDYJ5hoFXxpPcw3VXyecEBb+DAA5LWf6uH+7ZEEBcB-lWf5MM4TK1kWDZEtSIEqAAtjAADKVAAIJAcO5Cgh2DCIZyyEkGhmFUAAQnh87MoO4QkV23YSCh6FYZQIx-vh+IwfhUh8fOAktA0SZXHAz76qgZ6oAsAJrMCoHgicbJQloIBPuMa5IEIW7vqgn7zvmvxFgBgJgOBIGEWBwFQcBtgqG0lDHNBsHzvBjH4WRFEcbhbnMqBCE8Zi7JsZRlA0f5XYMcRwVIaF5HsVQXFwFc4kiKolAAIShIYsDORAEEOU5LlRGQqHUCQJCZHAcXlIJE4NWEwmwqJgxAA)